# For Loop in R only works for the last element

Tags: r, for-loop

```
Garages <- c('GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond','GarageType')
Bsmts <- c("BsmtExposure","BsmtFinType2","BsmtQual","BsmtCond","BsmtFinType1")

for (x in c(Garages, Bsmts) )
{
  data[[x]] <- factor( data[[x]], levels= c(levels(data[[x]]),c('None')))
  data[[x]][is.na(data[[x]])] <- "None"
}
```

I have two vectors storing columns which include missing values.
I try to use a 'for' loop to iterate through all these columns and replace missing values in these columns with "None" as a new level of these factor variables.

However, after running this code block, I only got the missing values of the "BsmtFinType1" column been replaced. Can someone tell me where is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce the issue with a small reproducible example

```
for (x in c(Garages, Bsmts) ) {
   data[[x]] <- factor( data[[x]], levels= c(levels(data[[x]]),c('None')))
   data[[x]][is.na(data[[x]])] <- "None"
 }

data
#  GarageFinish BsmtExposure
#1            a            d
#2            b            e
#3            c         None
#4         None            f
#5            a            g
```

---

It is possible that the `NA` values are strings `"NA"` and thus the `is.na` is failing to catch it on other columns except the last column where it is `NA`

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(GarageFinish = c('a', 'b', 'c', NA, 'a'), 
    BsmtExposure = c('d', 'e', NA, 'f', 'g'), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
Garages <- 'GarageFinish'
Bsmts <- 'BsmtExposure'
```